# Laravel Eloquent - Loading query scopes eagerly

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, relationships

I have a data structure in which I need objects to be aware of their needed dependencies for loading.

**What I can do**

Currently, I can do this to load the first layer of relationships, this is obviously a very basic model:

```
class Ticket {

    public function notes(){}
    public function events(){}
    public function tags(){}

    public function scopeWithAll($query)
    {
        $query->with('notes', 'events', 'tags');
    }

}

// Loads Ticket with all 3 relationships
$ticket = Ticket::withAll();
```

This works great!  The problem being, I need to chain this functionality down to 3-5 levels of dependent relationships.  Each of the 3 loaded models is going to have n relationships of its own.

I know I can do this through eager loading if I specify all of the relationship names, as follows:

```
public function scopeWithAll($query)
{
    $query->with('notes.attachments', 'notes.colors', 'events', 'tags', 'tags.colors.', 'tags.users.email');
}
```

This works great too.  But I need my code to be smarter than that.

**What I need to do**

Statically defining the scope of each object load is not desirable at this point in my project.  I need to be able to load a Ticket, and the Ticket load all of its relationships, and each of those relationships load all of their relationships.

The only way I can think to do this is find some way to eagerly load a query scope for each relationship on the class.  Something like

```
public function scopeWithAll($query)
{
    $query->with('notes.withAll()', 'events.withAll()', 'tags.withAll()');
}
```

Is there currently a way to do this within Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
User::withRelatives()->find(1);
```

Okay, that's an idea and how to implement that? For example, if you have some related methods for your `User` model such as 'posts', 'roles' etc then keep all the related methods (methods that make relationship) in a separate `trait`, for example:

```
trait UserRelatives {
    public function posts()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, in the `User` model you may create a `scopeMethod` like `withAll` and inside there you may try something like this:

```
public function scopeWithAll($query)
{
    // Get all the related methods defined in the trait
    $relatives = get_class_methods(UserRelatives::class);
    return $query->with($relatives);
}
```

So, if you do something like this:

```
$user = User::withAll()->find(1);
```

You'll be able to load all related models. Btw, `get_class_methods(UserRelatives::class)` will give you an array of all methods defined in that trait which may look something like this:

```
['posts', 'roles']
```

So, `User::withAll()` will load all the related models and then run the `query`.So, as a result the scope will do something like this:

```
$query->with(['posts', 'roles']);
```

Well, this is an abstract idea but hope you got it. Share your idea if you found something better.

### Update:

According to your Model and related methods, this may look something like this:

```
class Ticket {

    use TicketRelativesTrait;

    public function scopeWithAll($query)
    {
        $relatives = get_class_methods(TicketRelativesTrait::class);
        return $query->with($relatives);
    }
}
```

Trait:

```
trait TicketRelativesTrait {
    public function notes(){}
    public function events(){}
    public function tags(){}
}


// Loads Ticket with all relationships
$ticket = Ticket::withAll()->find(1);
```

This is more dynamic, no need to mention the related methods and whenever you add a new relationship method in the trait, that will also be loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  As far as I can tell this solution still has the same problem that I currently have.  I cannot chain those withAll() scopes down into the next objects.

For example, I would then need notes(), events(), and tags() to each load with their own withAll() query scopes.

Comment: I've got it and this is just an example to how you can do same for each model you have. So, you may need to create `withAll` for every models.